# json_encode does not work with strings as indexes

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I have an array like this :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 12 [2] => Essener [3] => 1 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 12 [2] => Dinkel Spezial [3] => 0.2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => Essener [3] => 1 )
)
```

and I use `json_encode` and echo it, I get this:

```
[["1","12","Essener","1"],["2","12","Dinkel Spezial","0.2"],["1","1","Essener","1"]]
```

which is good for me.

Now I have an array with `stdClass` Objects, which I wasn't able to transform into JSON with `json_encode`. When I echo it, it just doesn't show anything.

Then I transformed this array with objects to an array like this (with `get_object_vars()`):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 1 
        [item_name] => Essener
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 2 
        [item_name] => Dinkel Spezial
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 3 
        [item_name] => Saatenbrot
    )
)
```

and when I use `json_encode` and echo it still doesn't show anything. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what I need to do to get a JSON array?

I need this json array to send data to an IOS App.

Comment: json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Note:
>   In the event of a failure to encode, [json_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) can be used to determine the exact nature of the error.

So you can try to detect the exact error by yourself. From your information I can't see any error.

Furthermore I don't think, it doesn't return anything. Try to `var_dump()` the result of `json_encode()`. I assume it returns `false`, which means an error occured.

Answer (score 0):

So if anybody wondered what was wrong,
the problem was that i had "ä,ü,ö,ß" in my array and i needed to convert these to unicode and then everything worked just fine.